# Spring RabbitMQ convertAndSend is not working properly

Tags: spring, rabbitmq

I am using this code to queue data into RabbitMQ: https://www.javainuse.com/spring/spring-boot-rabbitmq-hello-world

I configured the following properties correctly to match the RabbitMQ configuration

- Host
- Username
- Password
- Exchange
- Routing key
- Queue

But `RabbitMQSender#send` or `rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchange, routingkey, company);` is not queuing any data into RabbitMQ and in the same time it's not returning any error

I tried to change the username or pwd to an incorrect one and I got `not_authorized` so the connection with correct username/pwd/queue/exchange/routingkey seems fine but it's not doing anything.

I tried to send event via Curl and it's working correctly, the event is queued correctly in RabbitMQ

```
curl  -v -u username:pwd -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" POST -d'{
    "properties": {
    },
    "routing_key": "my-routingkey",
    "payload":"hi",
    "payload_encoding": "string"
}' localhost:15672/api/exchanges/%2F/my-exchange/publish
```

Does the spring `RabbitTemplate#convertAndSend` execute in the background this API `localhost:15672/api/exchanges/%2F/my-exchange/publish` ?

If not, what I need to change in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to queue events into a remote RabbitMQ server which was not configured properly in `kubernetes`: it was missing the storage field `storage: 10Gi` and the RabbitMQ was failing silently ...

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
  image: rabbitmq:3.10.7-management
  persistence:
    storageClassName: managed-csi
    storage: 10Gi
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check whether exchange with the correct name is created